# How to get metadata of Salesforce Objects using Python if the object name is dynamic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

```
    from salesforce_api import Salesforce
    client = * connection details*
    desc_obj = client.sobjects.Case_Details__c.describe()
```

I want to the object name to be dynamic as it will be an user input. Something like:-

```
   from salesforce_api import Salesforce
   client = * connection details*
   def extract_sffields(table_name):
       desc_obj = client.sobjects.%table_name%.describe()
```

where table is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can use the builtins `getattr` and `setattr` to manipulate object attributes. So you can write:

```
desc_obj = getattr(client.sobjects, table_name).describe()
```

Comment: Thank you @progmatico. This worked for me. Appreciate your response.